# How can I make this RegEx into JavaScript RegExp object?

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, object

I have this RegEx which allows people to input max 7 digits before decimal and two after which is optional.

I figure it would be neater to put them into a variable.
I have searched through with people saying use the `RegExp` object but I am still confused how it's done.

This is what I have with my RegEx.

```
/^(\d{1,7})(\.\d{2})?$/
```

Comment: You may consider using `<input type="text" pattern="\d{1,7}(\.\d{2})?" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```js
var max1 = 7;
var max2 = 2;
var rx = new RegExp("^(\\d{1," + max1 + "})(\\.\\d{" + max2 + "})?$");
console.log(rx.test("1234567.12"));
console.log(rx.test("1234567.123"));
console.log(rx.test("12345678.12"));
```

Also, check these posts:

- [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066/why-do-regex-constructors-need-to-be-double-escaped)
- [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)
- [No regex delimiters are used with the `RegExp` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345664/regular-expression-for-allchars/18345735#18345735)

Comment: this is nice...never thought of extracting the max numbers out into variables. learned something new again... thx thx

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
var patt = new RegExp(/^(\d{1,7})(\.\d{2})?$/);
```

How to test:

```
console.log(patt.test('1234567ab')) : false

console.log(patt.test('1234567.12')) : true
```

Comment: Ok i got your point just pass limits into variable and append with pattern into RegExp